# How to find the logical path to application in startup.cs

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-1.0

In Startup.cs configure method when setting cookie authentication options the login path in the examples seem to reference a web root path.

https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/security/authentication/cookie.html

What if I am deploying the app in a virtual directory and do not want to hardcode it?

I could add the virtual directory to a config file but it seems like a step backwords. When I had similar issues before it seemed like i could use Url.Action or the VirtualPathUtility.  Is there something similar in asp.net core that can be used in startup.cs?

Comment: Does using `PathString` not put in the virtual directory?

Comment: Not for me. PathString produces a path identical to the one that I passed it though. I did find that there is an environment variable ASPNETCORE_APPL_PATH" that is present if the ConfigurationBuilder with the AddEnvironmentVariables() method is used.